# Determining if a time is between two other times

Tags: android, datetime, simpledateformat

I am trying to take hours that I've parsed using SimpleDateFormat and determining whether or not the current time is between the two sets of hours.  Basically, given a place's hours, I'm trying to determine if it is currently open our closed.

I am getting the current time by doing the following:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm");
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
int hour = now.get(Calendar.HOUR);
int minute = now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
String currentHour = Integer.toString(hour);
String currentMinute = Integer.toString(minute);
String timeNow = currentHour + ":" + currentMinute;
Date timeRightNow = sdf2.parse(timeNow);
```

Then, I determine whether `timeRightNow` is between the opening and closing times, I am doing the following:

```
if (timeOpen.before(timeRightNow) && timeClose.after(timeRightNow)) {
    openStatus = "open!";
} else { 
    openStatus = "closed."; 
}
```

Both `timeOpen` and `timeClose` are found by parsing a String using `sdf2` in the exact same way as `timeRightNow` is found.

Every time that this runs, it sets `openStatus` to "closed." even when the current time is between the open and close times.  Can anyone point me in the right direction to figure out why this is happening?

Comment: Are you perhaps having AM/PM woes? Tracing through with a debugger should reveal the source of the problem.

Comment: Or simply outputting what those times are and looking at them.

Comment: how do you calculate the timeOpen and timeClose?

Comment: The current time (currentHour, currentMinute) is calculating such that it is on 12-hour format, whereas the others are on 24-hour format.  This means that when it's put into sdf2, the current time (4:52) is not between, for example, 12:00 and 21:30. How can I get current time to be in 24:00 format (and therefore 16:52 instead of 4:52)?

Answer (score 1):

I changed `Calendar.HOUR` to `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY`.  This resolved the issue.